# Tech tree or tech levels

Tags: technological-development, futurology, worldbuilding-resources

Does anyone have a tech tree, or more preferably tech levels that start from stone age and then go to the far distant future. A link to the site or page that has it would be great. Also, I googled this heavily and I got lots of results, but none satisfied me. Can you give me a homebrew. It should have categories of tech like medical, and weapons.

Comment: You could look for the game Civilization. That would be a nice place to start and it's a good strategy game.

Comment: Science and technology don't really develop in a manner like that in "Tech Trees".  Instead there are revolutionary breakthroughs (e.g. internal combustion engines) followed by both scientific advancement (e.g. Carnot investigations into steam engines) and technological advancement of the concept (today's internal combustion engines are far better by every measure than those of 100 years ago).  Some advances (like lasers) have no obvious use when invented but eventually become crucial for many other advances.  I'd say technical development looks more like a web than a tree.

Comment: Related (if not a duplicate): http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/4122/classification-system-and-measure-of-progress-for-science-and-technology-branche

Comment: @Jim2B Agreed, progression of technology would be one weird looking tree. Tech trees are objects from strategy games. They are meant to both emulate natural evolution of technology and limit access to technology and generally organise progression. Mathematically speaking, human tech tree would be one big, complex generic graph. A [timeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_historic_inventions) might be more suited.

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of games that actually have this kind of treemap:

civilization is the one I actually prefer:
http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_technologies_in_Civ5

also, for the "future part" "anno 2070" can give you some clues:
http://anno2070.wikia.com/wiki/File:Tech_tree_poster.pdf

another nice source for future tech could be this:
https://postconsole.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/alien-crossfire-technolgogy.jpg

by the way, I suggest you to start from simulation games that involve "building things" maybe meshing up some concepts.